# Anyone have experience with PC-Lint used with Netbeans or MPLAB X IDE?

Tags: c, netbeans, static-analysis, mplab, pc-lint

I've been using PC-Lint with MPLAB for a couple of years now and it has been really useful.  MPLAB is about to change to be a netbeans based IDE and I've not found any netbeans plugins for PC-Lint.

Does anyone have experience in PC-Lint integration with netbeans or MPLAB X IDE?

TIA

Comment: Microchip have now said they've released a plug-in for PC-Lint, see http://www.microchip.com/forums/tm.aspx?m=539884&high=lint

Comment: WARNING WITH PLUG-IN! The lint process works fine on individual files but doesn't lint across files.  The plug-in applies lint on a file by file basis i.e. if you have 2 files then lint.exe will be run twice.  What it needs to do is to be run once on all of the files.  This helps reduce redundancy on a project for things shared between files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @fluffyben said, Microchip [announced](http://www.microchip.com/forums/fb.ashx?m=591067) a plugin release for PC-Lint.

I'll put here how to proceed:

- **From within MPLAB X select menu Tools|Plugins**

[image: Select Tools|Plugins]

- **Select Settings tab**

[image: Select Settings tab]

- **Click `Add` button and add the following URL:** http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/mplab/X_Beta/plugins/updates.xml

[image: Add URL]

- **In the "Available Plugins" tab, find PCLint, select it and install.**

[image: Select PCLint and install]

- **Verify if PCLint is installed in the "Installed" tab.**

[image: PCLint installed]

- **Close plugins window and select menu Help|Help Contents**

[image: Menu Help Contents]

- **Now go through the help file because usage is different from the MPLAB 8.**

[image]